# Google colab No labels found in <path>

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I am trying to train a YOLOV8 object detection model. I have imported all the required libraries and have successfully mounted the google drive and got the folders that I need.

Note that I have seen many posts on github and stackoverflow about the same issue but nothing worked for me.

This is how my structure looks for the images and labels:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkax4.png)

Here is the code for getting the libraries and training the model:

```
!pip install ultralytics
!pip install Ipython


#Install YOLOV8 libraries
from IPython import display
display.clear_output()

import ultralytics
ultralytics.checks()

#Mount the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


#Babesia dataset 1
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2
from ultralytics import YOLO

#Use pre-trained model
!yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolov8s.pt data=data.yaml epochs =2 plots=True
```

This is my data.yaml file:

```
train: /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/images/train/trainImages
val: /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/images/valid/validImages

nc: 1
names: ['Babesiidae']
```

And this is the error I get:

```
train: Scanning /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/train/trainImages... 0 images, 457 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100% 457/457 [00:11<00:00, 41.26it/s] 
train: WARNING ⚠️ No labels found in /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/train/trainImages.cache. See https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/detect for dataset formatting guidance.
train: New cache created: /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/train/trainImages.cache
WARNING ⚠️ No labels found in /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/train/trainImages.cache, training may not work correctly. See https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/detect for dataset formatting guidance.
albumentations: Blur(p=0.01, blur_limit=(3, 7)), MedianBlur(p=0.01, blur_limit=(3, 7)), ToGray(p=0.01), CLAHE(p=0.01, clip_limit=(1, 4.0), tile_grid_size=(8, 8))
val: Scanning /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/valid/validImages... 0 images, 57 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100% 57/57 [00:15<00:00,  3.62it/s]
val: WARNING ⚠️ No labels found in /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/valid/validImages.cache. See https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/detect for dataset formatting guidance.
val: WARNING ⚠️ Cache directory /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/valid is not writeable, cache not saved.
WARNING ⚠️ No labels found in /content/drive/MyDrive/Babesia - dataset2/Data/labels/valid/validImages.cache, training may not work correctly. See https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/detect for dataset formatting guidance.
Plotting labels to runs/detect/train/labels.jpg... 
zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

As mentioned,I have checked on many other posts to try and solve the issue. I have also tried to change the folder structure by having my labels with their respective image folder which is what other posts suggested, but it produces the same error.